# How to make link change the css in the following page

Tags: php, html, css

Is it possible to create a button which is href and when it leads to another page it hides one of the divs in the following page?

Thank you.

Comment: yes it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a parameter in anchor tag and check in the second page

EXAMPLE BELOW

**First Page**

```
<a href="test.php?hide=div2"><input type="button" name="button" value="Click Here" /></a>
```

**Second Page**

```
<?php
$hide = isset($_REQUEST['hide']) ? $_REQUEST['hide'] : '';
?>

<div id="div1" style="margin:10px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget aliquet nisi, sit amet tincidunt ex. Mauris quis volutpat dolor, et vehicula nisi. Maecenas iaculis placerat massa. In congue, justo et imperdiet dapibus, enim sapien auctor diam, vitae vestibulum sem magna eu risus. 
</div>

<?php
if ($hide != 'div2')
{
?>
<div id="div2" style="margin:10px;">
Integer quam dui, feugiat ac nisl vulputate, pellentesque egestas sapien. Nam semper mollis nisi, vitae viverra mauris iaculis ac. Suspendisse dictum efficitur turpis non interdum. Quisque mattis scelerisque odio, sed euismod neque faucibus nec. Donec purus est, cursus vitae neque ac, sollicitudin dictum neque. Sed id molestie ipsum. Sed pellentesque ipsum in mi luctus, eu aliquam quam auctor. Nam ullamcorper sit amet urna vitae ullamcorper. Donec purus urna, porttitor quis vestibulum eget, maximus et arcu. Suspendisse cursus faucibus eros, vel faucibus ante.
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<div id="div3" style="margin:10px;">
Sed maximus nibh vitae nunc aliquam, id iaculis diam suscipit. Ut id sem tincidunt, molestie mi et, vehicula nunc. Cras eget turpis vel nisi volutpat dapibus faucibus quis enim. Aenean ut libero nibh. Curabitur aliquet mauris ex, ut facilisis elit molestie at. Integer nec ultricies turpis. Cras molestie dapibus placerat. Mauris luctus fringilla dolor, sit amet consequat ante consectetur et. Nulla nec arcu placerat erat faucibus mollis id ut risus. Nam pulvinar diam elit, quis lobortis massa lobortis nec. Vestibulum et vulputate tortor. Donec sollicitudin, nisl et egestas malesuada, sem neque finibus justo, et pharetra sapien eros eu ipsum. Nulla sit amet faucibus lacus. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

make

```
 <a href="yourlink.php?variable=hidden">test</a>
```

and in your page

```
 <?php if(empty($_GET['variable'])): ?>
   <div class="div_Hidden">
     ....
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```